# Elastic query with an aggregation on a nested field and a sub aggregation on field (from root) returns empty array of buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, elasticsearch-aggregation

I Wrote a query with an aggregation on a nested field and a sub aggregation on a field that is not nested but in the root instead. I expected to get a sum for each ownerId, but instead I got an empty bucket array.

The following query returns an empty array of buckets - though there are results and a positive sum.

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg_owner": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "owner_fields"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "raw_names": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "owner_fields.id.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_amount": {
              "reverse_nested": {},
              "aggs": {
                "total_inner_amount": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "amount",
                    "size": 10
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

returns:

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 45430,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "agg_owner" : {
      "doc_count" : 15494,
      "raw_names" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [ ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expected to see a sum for each ownerId,
But that didn't happen.

Comment: Got the mapping and some sample docs?

Answer (score 0):

had to remove keyword from aggregation:
"owner_fields.id.keyword" => "owner_fields.id"